# Java/Android: Showing Miliseconds from a Time Instance?

Tags: java, android, time

I have an Instance of `Time`within my code, for which I am currently showing the `Hour`, `minute` and `second`. However I would also like to show the `milliseconds`. I cant seem to find a milliseconds option.

How can I Do so?

**Current Code Snippet:**

```
Time time2 = new Time();
                time2.setToNow();
                String seconds2 = time2.hour
                        + ":"
                        + (time2.minute < 10 ? "0" + time2.minute
                                : time2.minute)
                        + ":"
                        + (time2.second < 10 ? "0" + time2.second
                                : time2.second);
```

Comment: Get the millisecond and mod it with 1000. `time2.toMillis(true) % 1000`

Comment: are you looking for something like this **System.currentTimeMillis()**

Comment: I think she wants to get the millisecond component of the current time, not the typical millisecond timestamp.

Comment: Yeah I want the milisecond component, not the timestamp! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formatting the Time with `:` you can try Calander:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Whereas you can have DateFormat patterns such as:

"HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 12:08:56.235-0700

"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
"h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way of doing it using time?

Comment: no i guess, refer this [Time Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millisecond = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way of doing it using time?

Comment: Maybe, i'm not sure. There are numerous ways to handle date/time in  Java. Each way has it's own quirks. I usually pick one that get's the job done with the least amount of pain and is some way inline with the Android way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using either `java.util.Date`, or `java.util.Calendar`.

Using the former, you create a Calendar object, and then get the time in milliseconds from it, as follows:

> Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
>
> cal.getTimeInMillis();

You can use the Date object as follows:

> String dateFormattingRule = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss";
>
> DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormattingRule);
>
> String currentTime = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way of doing it using time?